# GCP VM unable to connect to ftp server

Tags: ftp, google-cloud-platform

I created a vm on gcp in the south america region with public ip to connect to the ftp server 189.9.32.26. On the firewall I opened ingress and egress tcp port 20 and 21 for this vm, but I still can't connect. ftp: connect: Connection timed out is returned. I have tested the connection of an aws and ec2 locally. In both cases, I succeeded.

Comment: Is FTP connecting in active or passive mode?

Comment: I don't know how to test this. What is the default for a vm in gcp?

Comment: Depends on the tool on the client side.